# Scroll bar not scrolling after active div is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed menu system that slides out and covers 100% of the screen once it is pressed. When it is active the the main scrollbar you will have the ability to scroll through the menu in the active div. Once you close the menu the scrollbar will not allow me to scroll the whole site anymore, it will only scroll the length of the div the slides out.

How can I fix this issue? I need the scrollbar to control the menu once it is active, then have the ability to scroll the whole site once the menu is not active.

Here is my JS and the full code http://jsfiddle.net/8P9kh/8/

```
$(function(){
    window.status=0;
$('#menu').click(function(){
    if(window.status==0){
        $('#slidingMenu').stop().animate({left:'0px'},500); 
        window.status=1;
        $('body, html').css('overflow','hidden');
    }
    else{
        $('#slidingMenu').stop().animate({left:'-100%'},500);
        window.status=0;
        $('body, html').css('overflow-y','scroll');
    }
});
})

//Close menu when you click Footer

$('#more').click(function () {
var open = $('header').is('.open');
$('#dropFooter')['slide' + (open ? 'Up' : 'Down')](400);
$('header').animate({
    bottom: (open ? '-' : '+') + '=200'
}, 400, function () {
    $('header').toggleClass('open');
});
});

$('#menu').click(function () {
if ($('').is('.open')) {
    $('')
        .removeClass('open')
        .animate({
        'bottom': "-=200"
    }, function () {
        var $footer = $('.activetoggle');

        if ($footer.length) 
            $footer
                .toggleClass('activetoggle footerButton')
                .text('Footer');
    });
    $('footer').slideUp(400);
}
});



$('.footerButton').click(function () {// Change wording once pressed
var $this = $(this);
$this.toggleClass('footerButton');
if ($this.hasClass('footerButton')) {
    $this.text('Footer');
} else {
    $this.text('Close');
}
$(this).toggleClass('activetoggle');
});

$(window).resize(function(){ //check when window resize
if($(window).width() < 780){ // check when the window width is less than 780 
if ($('header').is('.open')) { 
    $('header')
        .removeClass('open')
        .animate({
        'bottom': "-=200"                
    });
    $footer = $('.activetoggle');
    if ($footer.length) {
         $footer.toggleClass('activetoggle footerButton').text('Footer');
    }
    $('#dropFooter').slideToggle(400);
}
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're setting the CSS `overflow` property to `hidden` when the menu shows up, but then setting `overflow-x` property to `scroll`, leaving the `overflow` property at `hidden`. Reset the `overflow` property back to `auto`:

```
$('body, html').css('overflow', 'auto');
```

Comment: I tried that and its still doing the same thing @NobleMushtak

Comment: That's weird...It worked when I tried it. Sorry! @user3756781

Comment: yeah I see it working there, but on my site it is not work. @NobleMushtak

Comment: Hm...That's weird...Do you know what the differences are between your site and the frame source created on JSFiddle? @user3756781

Comment: No clue I am looking through my code. I do notice though when I tested the code by itself it displays a secondary scrollbar leaving the main scrollbar inactive @NobleMushtak

Comment: it seems when the footer slides up when the menu is open it blocks the scrolling @NobleMushtak

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you said that when the menu opens, the scrolling is blocked. Isn't that what's supposed to happen, though?

Comment: I'm sorry. Everything think works the way it supports to.But when the menu is open and you click footer the menu slides in displaying the footer content. But when you close the footer the scrollbar stops functioning @NobleMushtak